# Enabling drag and drop with Gridster.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am attempting to user [Gridster.js](http://gridster.net) to have an editable drag and drop grid ([as per the example here on their home page](http://gridster.net/#intro)).

I have setup a really basic example, to get it working - it all appears great, and I can select elements to move, but everything always just resets back to the original position, and none of the the other shapes get displace ad I am dragging an element (If you see their example, as you drag one element, the others get displaced in real time).

My html is as per their recommendation:

```
<div class="gridster ready">
    <ul style="position: relative; height: 360px;">
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2" class="gs_w widget-orange">loading</li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w widget-orange">loading</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w widget-orange">loading</li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w widget-orange">loading</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w widget-orange">loading</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my JS is as per theirs on the home page:

```
 var gridster;
  $(function(){

    gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({
        widget_margins: [20, 20],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
        min_cols: 6
    }).data('gridster');

  });
```

Does anyone have any ideas? has anyone used this library?  (I don't have any errors logged in dev tools in chrome console etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work you need to remove the `ready` class from the unordered list. Gridster adds it automatically when it loaded the plugin correctly, because it's already there, it doesn't load properly.

Comment: Yep, worked that out but forgot to come back and update the answer - but this is right, so will accpet it - thanks!